# How to find the basic reproductive number $R_0$ of a non-autonomous dynamical system?

Tags: dynamical-systems, mathematical-modeling, stability-theory

How to find the basic reproductive number $R_0$ of a non-autonomous dynamical system? For instance given a dynamical system

$X'=-\delta\frac{X(I+E)}{N}+\epsilon M+\mu N-\mu X$
$I'=\delta\frac{X(I+E)}{N}-(1-sinBt)\alpha_1 I+(1+sin Bt)\alpha_2 E-\gamma I-\mu I$

$E'=(1-sinBt)\alpha_1 I-(1+sin Bt)\alpha_2 E-\mu E$

$M'=\gamma I-\epsilon M-\mu M$.

Can someone show me how to solve the $R_0$ of this dynamical system? or give any references that would lead in solving the $R_0$ of this system.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/users/29547/artem